# Regex Help Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this code:

```
import re
#TEST CASES
match_dict = ['hello(here)',
             'Hello   (Hi)',
             "'dfsfds Hello (Hi) fdfd' Hello (Yes)",
             "Hello ('hi)xx')",
             "Hello  ('Hi')"]
for s in match_dict:
    print "INPUT: %s" % s
    m = re.sub(r"(?<!\()'[^']+'", '', s, flags=re.M)
    paren_quotes = re.findall(r"Hello\s*\('([^']+)'\)", m, flags=re.M)
    output = paren_quotes if paren_quotes else []
    m = re.sub(r"Hello\s*\('[^']+'\)", '', m, flags=re.M)
    paren_matches = re.findall(r"Hello\s*\(([^)]+)\)", m, flags=re.M)
    if paren_matches:
        output.extend(paren_matches)
    print 'OUTPUT: %s\n' % output
```

This code is made to output everything in the parentheses after the word 'Hello',

```
Hello (Hi)  would give 'Hi'
```

My problem is that when I put in:

```
Hello('Hi')
```

...It still returns `'Hi'`   when I want it to return `"'Hi'"`

Does anyone know how could I fix this code?

Comment: Please use an appropriate title which shortly describes your problem. We know that you need help, otherwise you would not ask. We also know that your question is about regular expressions and Python because it is tagged as such.

Comment: So... You're trying to capture the text between parentheses?

Comment: Am I wrong, or does this seem like an overcomplicated approach to the goal?

Comment: Yeah but theres a few rules I have created,

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is a great tool to mess around with RegEx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use non-greedy matching:

```
matches = re.search(r'^Hello\s*\((.*?)\)', text)
```

Comment: This test case shouldn't work: "'Hello             (f)   '" , there should be nothing returned because the Hello statement is in quotes

Comment: Why does it need to be so complicated?

Comment: @user1357159: I think that no matter what you suggest about the rules, Blender is just going to modify the regex to suit in less code than you were attempting.

Comment: You know the rules and so do I,  ;;Ok, enough of that, this works pretty well.

Comment: @user1357159: Truthfully, I would consider simplifying the problem by first getting rid of that "Hello" part. After that just use regex to extract the text within the parentheses and finally classify it to your needs.

Comment: @user1357159: regular expressions are not very good at parsing, if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Blender ,, Im having an issue, Hello(7)  doesn't work, because there is no space in between Hello and (7), How can I make it accept Hello(7)

Comment: @JoelCornett What might you recommend

Comment: @user1357159: then make the whitespace optional: `\s*`

Comment: ^Hello\s*+\((.*?)\) , If I do that, I get an error "Multiple Repeat"

Comment: @user1357159: you are doubling up * and +. Just replace it. I made an edit for Blender

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'Hello\s*\((.*?)\)', re.M)
>>> m = p.findall("Hello  ('Hi')")
>>> print m
["'Hi'"]
>>> m = p.findall("'dfsfds Hello (Hi) fdfd' Hello (Yes)")
>>> print m
['Hi', 'Yes']
```